# Website Technical Issue - Traling Slash Issue - Page Speed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

We are having our own website https://www.preciouscarbon.com/ and the technology that we have used is wordpress woocommrce.

Since starting the buildig the website we are facing many issue like pages speed issue, Jss and CSS isssue, few pages having two versions with "/" and without "/",

Also we have only one XML sitemap https://www.preciouscarbon.com/sitemap.xml but while SEO team checking the Google Search Console it showing multiple.

Can expert who have idea of eCommerce website can review our website and give best suggestions or solutions that we can apply, please let us know.

We request to community to help us here what is the best solution that we have to apply.

Looking forward to positive response.

I am trying to find the technical solutions of our website, looking for solutions.

Comment: You can't ask many questions at once… The rule on Stack overflow is one question at the time. Also, we expect you to provide, in your question, some related code. Then you can explain what is the problem you are facing, we can not "debug" with so little info. Please go read How to Ask and minimal reproducible example, and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check the website server,

1. A lite speed server
2. Or any other.

If you're website having litespeed server then install the litespeed cache plugin.

or have any other server then go with the wprocket plugin.

if you need more help you can reach me out.

Thanks